# get_item in Lambda to read one item from dynamodb table having issues

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a simple table with agentId (PK) and agentRole(SK). I am trying read one item from that table. Using boto3 client

I am getting syntax error on print statement.

```
   import json
   import boto3

   client = boto3.client('dynamodb')

   def lambda_handler(event, context):
       response = client.get_item(
            TableName='USBCallCenterTable',
            Key={
                'agentId': {
                    'N': str(1)
                 },
                'agentRole':{
                     'S': 'Manager'
                 }
             }
    
       )
      print(response)
```

"errorMessage": "name 'response' is not defined",
"errorType": "NameError",
"requestId": "",[image]

Comment: Isn’t the print statement inside the get_item, causing the syntax error?

Answer (score 1):

Print is not an argument of get_item. Try to put the print outside get_item. I think it should solve the problem.